# Variable que contiene data de una api se encuentra vacia

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, fetch

Hola tengo un problema al tratar de rertornar y guardar la data de una api, lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
  const items = []

  const PATH_PRODUCT_ID = `/api/items`
  fetch(PATH_PRODUCT_ID, { credentials: 'omit' })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((products) => {
      products.forEach((product) => {
        items.push(product)
      })
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error('customData', err))
```

al hacer un console.log al array que les estoy pasando los items, me imprime el array con los objetos

```
  console.log('Alert Items -> ', items)
```

Pero si quiero iterar sobre ellos con un .forEach() o un for corriente no puedo hacerlo, ademas al hacerle un console.log() a la longitud del array me imprime 0.

```
  console.log('lenght of items -> ', items.length)
```

En la consola:

```
lenght of items ->  0
```

Que puedo estar haciendo mal? Gracias.

Comment: cual es la salida de esto? `console.log('Alert Items -> ', items)`

Comment: De dónde salió `suggestedProducts`? No veo que le estés asignando nada a ese supuesto arreglo.

Comment: Además... recuerda que `fetch` es asincrono... será que no estás esperando que el `fetch` termine de hacer su tarea y estaras intentando usar `items` por fuera antes de que fetch termine?

Comment: perdon, fue un error, suggestedProducts, es en realidad el arreglo items que esta declarado, y se que fetch es asincrono pero tambien intente creando una funcion asincrona que devuelva la data, pero al asignarselo a una variable, esta me imprime una promesa, y si le coloco await antes de llamar a la funcion, me da un error de compilacion.

Comment: En principio lo que desees hacer con items deberías hacerlo dentro del 2do then, es la forma que tienes de asegurarte de que la repuesta está, incluso podrías eliminar el array y utilizar directamente la response. Otra opción es pasar la llamada a async y await y luego de recibir la respuesta hacer lo que desees.

Comment: 3 pregustas, estas usasndo reactjs?, el primer boque lo tenes dentro de una funcion en un archivo a parte?, si el primer bloque esta en una funcion, el console.log que probaste que te dio los items, lo probaste dentro de la funcion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás intentando recorrer un objeto, el cual no es iterable, por lo tanto no estás insertando nada en `items`.

Para poder recorrer un objeto, primero tienes que convertirlo en un array, para ello tendrás que hacer uso de uno de los siguientes métodos de `Object`:

- `Object.keys`: Devuelve un iterable con las claves del objeto.
- `Object.values`: Devuelve un iterable con los valores (sin la clave).
- `Object.entries`: Devuelve un iterable de conjuntos de clave y valor.

Sabiendo esto, vamos a añadir los datos de la respuesta al array `items`:

Deduzco que no te interesa almacenar las claves, por lo tanto lo conveniente es usar `Object.values`

```
const PATH_PRODUCT_ID = `/api/items`
 
// Solicita los datos a la API.
fetch(PATH_PRODUCT_ID, { credentials: 'omit' })
    // Resuelve la solicitud y parsea la respuesta en JSON.
    .then((response) => response.json())
    
    // Resuelve la promesa del parseo de la respuesta.
    .then((products) => {
        
        // Pasa a iterable y recorre.
        Object.values(products).forEach(product => {

            // Inserta el producto de la iteración.
            items.push(product);

        });

        // Resto del código...
        // Recuerda que fetch es asíncrono.

    })
    // Manejo de errores.
    .catch((err) => console.error('customData', err))
```

Pero como recorrer la salida para volver a insertar los datos en un array no es óptimo, podrías declarar `items` como variable en vez de constante y asignar la salida de `Object.values`:

```
let items;

...

    // Resuelve la promesa del parseo de la respuesta.
    .then((products) => {
    
        // Pasa a iterable y recorre.
        items = Object.values(products);

        // Resto del código...
        // Recuerda que fetch es asíncrono.

    })
```

Échale un ojo a este snippet:

```js
// Ignorar esta función.
const fetchAPI = () => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({
        product1: {
            name: 'product1',
          price: '12,99',
          description: '...'
        },
        product2: {
            name: 'product2',
          price: '25,99',
          description: '...'
        },
        product3: {
            name: 'product3',
          price: '50,99',
          description: '...'
        },
      })
    }, 800)
  
  })

}

// Empezar a leer por aquí.
const items = [];

// Simula la petición a la API.
fetchAPI()
//.then(response => response.json())
.then(products => {

    // Pasa a iterable el resultado de la petición.
    Object.values(products).forEach(product => {
    
    // Asigna el producto al array items.
    items.push(product);
    
  });
  
  // Muestra la cantidad de índices en el array items.
  console.log(`length of items -> ${items.length}`);

})
```

También te recomiendo que revises la documentación de MDN:

- [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)
- [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)